# Can't install android dev env on linux

Tags: android

I tried using directly the sdk manager, using android studio, and using the ADT tools, whenever i try to run any of the above IDEs it gives me the following error:

*Cannot run program "/home/igeeko/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-
tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory' while attempting to get adb version from '/home/igeeko/Downloads/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb*

how to get over it? i did not tamper with any android file, i just decompressed the compressed file and executed the executable file.

EDIT: i am using Xubuntu 13.04, I have not tried command line, i downloaded the ADT bundle from developer.android.com, extracted it and then tried to execute the executable file, i also got this error message, [image: error message i am getting]

i am able to create a virtual device, but not able to run it, it says that the "adb" file does not exist, it is there, and i have given read & write permissions to everyone on the file, so what might be the problem? and i am trying this since a long time

Comment: Could you provide some further info on your operating system and solutions you've already tried? Have you tried running from command line or is that just double clicking the .exe?

Comment: no i don't know how to use the commandline, i downloaded the adt bundle and extracted it, then double clicked on the executable file

Comment: I would check the directory's correct, (Sorry, if that sounds patronizing.) and then check it's executable. From the command line navigate to the directory: `cd ~/ADT/sdk/platform-tools/` and then try `./adb`. To ensure it's executable, from the same directory, run `chmod +x ./adb`

Comment: Actually i re installed my system and it works fine now